# how to calculate the joint probability of a sequence of events being larger than different values

Tags: python, statistics, probability, combinatorics

Lets imagine I have the following distribution of values:

| Value | N Cases | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 60 | 60 |
| 1 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 8. | 8 |
| 4 | 2. | 2 |

```
import pandas as pd
from math import factorial
from itertools import product

Value = [0,1,2,3,4]
N_freq = [60,20,10,8,2]
Perc = [0.60,0.20,0.10,0.08,0.02]


df = pd.DataFrame({"Value": Value, "N_freq":N_freq, "Perc":Perc})
df
```

- The probability of X>=0 is 100%
- The probability of X>=1 is 40%

If I want to calculate the probability of the sequence of events X_{1}>=0, X_{2}>=0, X_{3}>=1 (assuming independence of events and no order), I would do 100%*100%*40% = 40%.

However, the only event left or not included in this sequence IS (0,0,0), which probability is 60%*60%*60 = 21.6%. Therefore, the correct probability of X_{1}>=0, X_{2}>=0, X_{3}>=1 is 100%-21.6%.

What am I missing in the ponderation of cumulative probabilities ? Is there a way to do it that does not include calculating all the possibilities of events then summing them (when the number of values is very large, that is not doable).

This is how I would do it:
from functools import reduce

```
def CombinationsVectorWithReplacementAndOrder(vect):
    """
    This code calculates all potential combinations of a vector with replacement and order 
    vec: vector of whatever length with integers inside
    The formula applied is:
    
    Result = !/ ∏∈(,)!, 
    where D is the lenght of vect,
    and s is number of times of each case happening in the vector.
    
    For simplification, non existent cases (which will compute as 0! =1 will not be included since they are not required)
    
    It returns an integer value saying the total amount of combinations of that vector
    """
    d = len(vect) # Length of sequence
    # Numerator
    NumeratorFormula = factorial(d)
    
    # Denominator
    df_vec = pd.DataFrame(vect, columns = ["vec_values"]).vec_values.value_counts().values
    
    # If the case is unique, then it is directly the factorial of the number
    if len(df_vec)==1:
        DenominatorFormula = factorial(df_vec)
    else:
        DenominatorFormula = 1
        for val in df_vec:
            DenominatorFormula=DenominatorFormula*factorial(val)
    
    # Result
    Formula = NumeratorFormula/DenominatorFormula
    return int(Formula)

def CumProbWithNoOrder(df, Vals):
    MaxVal = df["Value"].max()
    ValList = [list(range(Val, MaxVal+1, 1)) for Val in Vals]
    l=list(product(*ValList))
    AllComb = [list(elem) for elem in l]
    UniqueComb =[]
    for i in AllComb:
        if sorted(i) not in UniqueComb:
            UniqueComb.append(sorted(i))
    TotalProb = 0         
    for Comb in UniqueComb :   
        Prob= float(pd.DataFrame([float(df["Perc"][df["Value"].isin([c])]) for c in Comb]).prod())
        Combinations = CombinationsVectorWithReplacementAndOrder(Comb)
        TotalProb += Prob*Combinations 
    print(f'the probability is', TotalProb )
    return TotalProb


Value = [0,0,1] #Values bigger or equal than Vals to evaluate 
CumProbWithNoOrder(df, Value) # 0.7840000000000001
```

Whatever thing that is not clear feel free to ask me.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Does your question is to find a fast way to calculate specificly >= kind of conditions?

Comment: yes, it is so. I have one way (I think), but I was thinking whether there is a faster way.

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Maybe it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question about the probability calculation. I think you might missed the not included sequences (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (3,4, 0)... The only requirement is that the last element is 0 regardless of the two elements before.

For your second question, I am not fimiliar with Pandas so I'll write my idea in basic python but I'm quite sure you can implement it using Pandas.
My idea is the following:
Before calculating any probabilities, calculate some things to help you later:
At first sort your dataset by values. That means first element is 0 then 1, 2, 3 and 4. After that make a list in the size of the number of different values you have (in this case 5). Now, for each value in your dataset add its percentage to all the list slots before. The code should look something like that:

```py
values_dataset = sorted(values_dataset)  # sort by value

number_of_different_values = 100  # int this case you have 5

lst = [0] * number_of_different_values  # list of >= probabilities
for i in range(len(values_dataset)):
    for j in range(i):  # add the probability to all the smaller values
        lst[j] += values_dataset[i].getPerc()
```

And that's all the calculations you need!
If you want to calculate the probability of (3,1,0) you just compute
`lst[3] * lst[1] * lst[0]`. That works because the `lst`'s `i`-th element is the probability to get a value which is greater or equals to the `i`-th value in the dataset.

Of course, this code can be improved, it's just an illustration of the idea. I hope may explanation was clear, and I understood your question right.

Comment: How would you do it without doing brute force (see my code)

Comment: Check my updated answer.